# How to rotate triangle collapse icon in Ext Js panel?

Tags: css, icons, panel, extjs4.1

Is there a way to rotate the collapse icon in a panel ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydGi7.png )? Since the direction is a bit misleading as the panel collapses in a direction opposite to that what the icon indicates.

```
   defaults: {
            collapsible: true,
            animFloat: true,
            autoHide: true,
            cmargins: '5 5 5 5'
        },
        items:
        [{
            xtype: 'createreportview',
            bodyStyle:{ padding: '10px'},
            minHeight:280,
            flex: 0.40
         },
         {
             xtype: 'splitter',
             collapseTarget:'prev'
         },
         {
             xtype: 'resultsview',
             flex: 0.60
        }]
}
```

There are 2 panels, the collapse icon on the 2nd panel (resultsview) is the one shown in the image posted above and is the one im trying to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just change the background-position of the image.  Here is the sprite of all the tool images: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/resources/themes/images/default/tools/tool-sprites.gif

if you go to http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/examples/layout/border.html and inspect the arrow elements (up and down arrows on the panels you can see the background-position values set in the css.

For position of down arrows:

```
x-tool-expand-top, .x-tool-collapse-top {
    background-position: 0 -210px;
}
```

Position of up arrows:

```
.x-tool-over .x-tool-expand-bottom, .x-tool-over .x-tool-collapse-bottom {
    background-position: -15px -195px;
}
```

You could update the css (using a stylesheet that loads after ext's css file) to the following to switch them (just switch background-positions):

```
.x-tool-expand-top, .x-tool-collapse-top {
    background-position: -15px -195px;
}

.x-tool-over .x-tool-expand-bottom, .x-tool-over .x-tool-collapse-bottom {
    background-position: 0 -210px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What's you layout for the parent container? I think you can just use `layout: border`, and specify `region: south` for you bottom panel and it will have down arrow.

As for trying to fix your exact sample - try to move `collapsible: true` from `defaults` inside bottom panel definition.

Comment: The layout was a vbox, changed it to border with the bottom panel as the `region:south` and the icon does orient itself properly now, but then to have the splitter i put `split:true`in `defaults`. The split pointer always points away from the center region panel, however i want it to point to the createreportview panel so that results can be fully expanded. Also tried setting `region:north` for the top panel but it again messes up the collapse direction.

Comment: Can u put a screenshot of what you have now? and also how the new code looks like?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/tM0V6.png currently the bottom panel is set to `region:center`. '1' in the image is how id like he split pointer to point to and expand to the top, but '2' collapses downwards even though it points upwards.

Comment: Usually one panel will not be collapsible in this case. It should get region: center. The only one will be collapsible and arrow will be properly pointed. How exactly do expect both of them to collapse?

Comment: Hmm, ideally id like them both to collapse either way, but the bottom panel is more important and would want it to collapse towards the top

Comment: That's the problem. I mean if you want to expand bottom panel all the way to the top - right way to do this is to present it to the user is as collapsing top panel to the top (leaving just header row)